# Is there a more efficient way of importing hundreds of tables using IMPORTHTML in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, import, sequence, yahoo-finance

We'll use stock market symbols/tickers as an example.

My sheet looks something like this: https://www.oldschoolvalue.com/wp-content/uploads/stock-portfolio-tracker-spreadsheet-google.png

The goal to paste in hundreds of stock symbols in the stock column, and everything on the right will auto-populate with all static/absolute values. It'll also only use 1 IMPORTHTML query for each stock symbol to avoid hitting any query limits.

- If I use IMPORTHTML to bring in a table for the symbol AAPL; it gives me a grid table, let's say 10x10, with all the information.
- I only need information from 10 cells, so I make 10 columns. Under each column is an INDEX(IMPORTHTML()) formula to index a specific cell.

Example IMPORTHTML table:
`=IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=aapl","table",8)`
Pick out 10 different values, whatever you want, as long as it's different rows and columns, not sequential. That's what I'm working with.

What I've got now works and is organized, but the problem is each of those formulas under each column for each row(stock symbol) has an IMPORTHTML query. So for every stock symbol there's 10 IMPORTHTML queries. If you've done something like this before, you'll know there's a limit to how many queries can be performed before it errors out or stays at "Loading..."

Problem with importing the whole table, is that if you put the IMPORTHTML formula in cell A1, it'll populate everything from A1:K10 or whatever the table size is; assuming the surrounding cells are empty. This would be a good option because it's only 1 IMPORTHTML query and it gives me all the information I need.

Also, I still haven't figured out how to make a formula turn itself into the value it generates. Example: if you do something like `=10*10`, the value will be 100, but the cell will still be `=10*10`. Should be a way to make the formula replace itself with the value of 100 after it calculates it. Also, include some sort of exception so it doesn't replace itself if it's an error or blank.

Comment: whats your formula. share a copy of your sheet. there is always a way how to get your 10 cells with just one formula. also, to convert =10*10 to 100 - this can be done only with script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say we want yellow cells:

[image]

imagine your table in terms of the sequence:

[image]

if you can tell how much cells there are you can use:

```
=SEQUENCE(144)
```

if not go for:

```
=SEQUENCE(COUNTA(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=aapl", "table", 8)))
```

next, put both in array `{}` like:

[image]

and now you just summon those yellow cells by a number in whatever order you like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(VLOOKUP({50; 27; 135; 88; 36; 42; 126; 56; 82; 95}, {SEQUENCE(144), 
 FLATTEN(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=aapl", "table", 8))}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]